# How to (capture) address the same element being accessed in Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to insert these chars inside quotes `"A", "B", ...` using regex replace in notepad++

> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z

I can use few other tricks for this problem but particularly I'm looking for a way to access the elements being replaced in to be replaced in every cases not just characters, numbers, or this particular pattern?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "in every case"?

Comment: What if I have to replace `a1s2fa342_-` this type of pattern with `$a1s2fa342_-$`

Comment: I've edited my answer to address this case, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for

```
(\w+)
```

and replacing all with

```
"\1"
```

would work for all alphanumeric "words".

For your second example, change the search term to

```
([\w-]+)
```

and the replacement term to

```
$\1$
```

Comment: `\1` means "the part of the match that's enclosed by the first pair of parentheses", so here it means "whatever `\w+` matched". If you have more than one pair, `\2` refers to the second set (counted from the opening parenthesis).

Comment: One more Questoin ... why didn't `[A-Z]` replaced with `"\1"` worked?

Comment: Because you didn't capture the match. `([A-Z])` would have worked - in your regex there is nothing for the `\1` to refer to. In most regex flavors, you can also use `\0` to refer to the entire match, but from what I've heard, `\0` doesn't work in Notepad++.

Comment: Woops!! thanks i got  it .. () was the trick!! Thanks ... it's a nice useful thing!!